# How to save ssh password for VS Code remote? (The server can only log in with a username and password, and does not support key pairs）

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

The server can only log in with a username and password, and does not support key pairs. so how to save password for VS Code remote?